# How to set the edit text disabled from other class

Tags: android-studio, android-edittext

How to set the edit text of other activity to be disabled when i click specific button.

because i have 2 buttons, which will eventually go to same layout. But I want when i click the 1st button, the edit text will be disabled/read only while if I clicked the 2nd button the edit text will be enabled.

Comment: Where is the first button? first button in first activity and edittext in second activity?

Comment: Sorry for unclear explanation, Yes, first and 2nd button in first activity while the edittext is on the second activity. If i click the button1, the edittext on the second activity will be disabled while if i click the 2nd button, editext on the 2nd activity can be edited.

Comment: Kindly upvote to my answer if it helps

Comment: Sorry, a while ago i have less than 15 reputation so i cant upvote your answer. Can you answer this question ? I needed it badly :(

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41954426/please-help-me-for-the-flow-of-my-application

Comment: Mention not. So, All this community members are always eager to help to other community member. Happy to be part of SO. Yes, definitely i will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE:** 
  The thing is, when the first activity visible, second activity will be pause state. while pause state, you cannot update the UI,. so what you can  do is, just pass one flag from first activity to second activity,based on the flag set the enable or disable operation on edittext.thats all.

```
Intent firstActivity= new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
firstActivity.putExtra("flag","disable");
startActivity(firstActivity);
```

in Second Activity,onCreate() method

```
String flag=getIntent().getStringExtra("flag");
if(flag.equals("disable")){
   edtText.setEnable(false);
}else{
   edtText.setEnable(true);
}
```